# Decompile WP8 assemblies

Tags: windows-phone-8, decompiling, .net-reflector, dotpeek

Anyone have clue, how to go about viewing the source from the Microsoft.Phone.dll [Windows Phone 8 ]. I tried this with the .Net reflector and JetBrains dot peek , Unfortunately it did not decompile the assembly. Any help much appreciated.?

Answer (score 2):

You need a WP8 Phone dump and extract System.Windows.dll from WP8Dump\3\Windows\System32 . Load that file as assembly in .Net reflector and you are on the way.
The dump was online here [xda developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1972146), if you find a new one, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Telerik JustDecompile? It is free to download [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).

**NOTE:** I am answering to help you but I am not condoning anything you are trying to do with the DLL code. I am not sure what you want the code for or even if it is legal to decompile it.